# Small datasheet code running super slow on Excel VBA

Tags: performance, vba, excel

The code has been super useful with my work datasheets.
They all have this pattern and the VBA code makes sure it all has the right format.

Why is it so slow?

Sometimes it takes 2~3 minutes to run a few lines of data.

```
Sub a_organizar_protocolo()
    On Error Resume Next

    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.InterActive = False

    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 90

    Columns("O:P").ClearContents
    Columns("R:R").ClearContents

    With Cells
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
        With .Borders
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With .Font
            .Name = "Calibri"
            .Size = 11
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Bold = False
            .Italic = False
        End With
    End With

    With Rows("1:1")
        .RowHeight = 32
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 49
        .WrapText = True
        With .Font
            .Size = 12
            .Bold = True
            .ColorIndex = 44
        End With
    End With

    With ActiveWindow
        .FreezePanes = False
        .SplitColumn = 0
        .SplitRow = 1
        .FreezePanes = True
    End With

    With Rows("2:" & Rows.Count)
        .RowHeight = 15
        .Interior.Color = xlNone
    End With

    Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 15
    Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 14
    Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 20
    Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 30
    Columns("E:E").ColumnWidth = 14
    Columns("F:F").ColumnWidth = 11
    Columns("G:G").ColumnWidth = 40
    Columns("H:H").ColumnWidth = 14
    Columns("I:I").ColumnWidth = 14
    Columns("J:J").ColumnWidth = 16
    Columns("K:K").ColumnWidth = 20
    Columns("L:L").ColumnWidth = 10
    Columns("M:M").ColumnWidth = 8
    Columns("N:N").ColumnWidth = 12
    Columns("O:O").ColumnWidth = 5
    Columns("P:P").ColumnWidth = 14
    Columns("Q:R").ColumnWidth = 25

    Range("A1").Value = "Lançamento"
    Range("B1").Value = "Data de Recebimento"
    Range("C1").Value = "Solicitante"
    Range("D1").Value = "Espécie do Documento"
    Range("E1").Value = "Número da Nota Fiscal"
    Range("F1").Value = "Código do Fornecedor"
    Range("G1").Value = "Fornecedor"
    Range("H1").Value = "Centro de Custo"
    Range("I1").Value = "Vencimento"
    Range("J1").Value = "Valor"
    Range("K1").Value = "Descrição"
    Range("L1").Value = "Pedido"
    Range("M1").Value = "Item do Pedido"
    Range("N1").Value = "Pagamento"
    Range("O1").Value = "Validação"
    Range("P1").Value = "Prioridade"
    Range("Q1").Value = "Observação"
    Range("R1").Value = "Concatenar"

    Dim qa, q1, q2, q3 As Range
    Set q1 = Range(Range("G2"), Range("G" & Rows.Count))
    Set q2 = Range(Range("J2"), Range("K" & Rows.Count))
    Set q3 = Range(Range("Q2"), Range("R" & Rows.Count))
    Set qa = Union(q1, q2, q3)
    qa.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft

    Dim ea, e1, e2 As Range
    Set e1 = Range(Range("G2"), Range("G2").End(xlDown))
    Set e2 = Range(Range("K2"), Range("K2").End(xlDown))
    Set ea = Union(e1, e2)
    With ea
        .Replace What:=".", Replacement:=""
        .Replace What:="/", Replacement:=""
        .Replace What:=":", Replacement:=""
        .Replace What:="–", Replacement:="-"
    End With

    Dim r0, ra As Range
    Set r0 = Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlDown))
    For Each ra In r0
        If Len(ra.Value) > 9 Then ra.Value = Right(ra.Value, 9)
    Next
    r0.Replace What:="x", Replacement:="0"

    Dim ta, tb As Range
    Dim t1, t2, t3, t4 As Range
    t0 = Range("E:E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    Set t1 = Range("E2:E" & t0)
    Set t2 = Range("F2:F" & t0)
    Set t3 = Range("H2:H" & t0)
    Set t4 = Range("L2:M" & t0)
    Set tb = Union(t1, t2, t3, t4)

    For Each ta In tb
        tc = ""
        For t = 1 To Len(ta.Value)
            td = Mid(ta.Value, t, 1)
            If td Like "[0-9]" Then
                te = td
            Else
                te = ""
            End If
        tc = tc & te
        Next t
        ta.Value = tc
    Next

    Dim ya, yb As Range
    Set yb = Range(Range("J2"), Range("J2").End(xlDown))

    For Each ya In yb
        yc = ""
        For y = 1 To Len(ya.Value)
            yd = Mid(ya.Value, y, 1)
            If yd Like "[0-9],-" Then
                ye = yd
            Else
                ye = ""
            End If
        yc = yc & ye
        Next y
        ya.Value = yc * 1
    Next

    Dim ia, ib As Range
    Set ib = Range(Range("J2"), Range("J2").End(xlDown))

    For Each ia In ib
        If ia.Value < 0 Then
            With ia
                .Offset(0, -1).Value = "31/12/" & (Year(Date) + 1)
                .Offset(0, -2).Value = "NA"
                .Offset(0, 2).Value = "NA"
                .Offset(0, 3).Value = "NA"
            End With
        End If
    Next

    Dim oa, ob As Range
    Set ob = Range(Range("D2"), Range("D2").End(xlDown))

    For Each oa In ob
        If oa.Value = "Ouvidoria" Then
            With oa
                .Offset(0, -1).Value = oa.Value
                .Offset(0, 8).Value = "NA"
                .Offset(0, 9).Value = "NA"
                .Offset(0, 10).Value = "DEPÓSITO"
            End With
        End If
    Next

    Dim pa, pb, p1, p2 As Range

    Set p1 = Columns("H:H").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    For Each pa In p1
        pa.Value = "Estoque"
    Next

    Set p2 = Range(Range("H2"), Range("H2").End(xlDown))
    For Each pb In p2
        If pb.Value = "Estoque" Then pb.Offset(0, -7).Value = pb.Value
    Next

    Dim k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, ka, kb, kaa, kbb As Range
    Set k1 = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    Set k2 = Range(Range("C2"), Range("C2").End(xlDown))
    Set k3 = Range(Range("G2"), Range("G2").End(xlDown))
    Set k4 = Range(Range("K2"), Range("K2").End(xlDown))
    Set k5 = Range(Range("N2"), Range("N2").End(xlDown))
    Set ka = Union(k1, k2)
    Set kb = Union(k3, k4, k5)

    For Each kaa In ka
        kaa.Value = StrConv(kaa.Value, vbProperCase)
    Next kaa

    For Each kbb In kb
        kbb.Value = UCase(kbb.Value)
    Next kbb

    Cells.Validation.Delete
    Cells.FormatConditions.Delete

    Range("E2").End(xlDown).Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.InterActive = True
End Sub
```

---

<sub>People from Stack Overflow redirected me here.</sub>

Comment: `For Each ta In tb`, `For Each ya In yb`, `For Each ia In ib`, `For Each oa In ob`, `For Each pa In p1`, `For Each kaa In ka`, `For Each kbb In kb` - all of these cell-by-cell read/write are slow.

Comment: Won't help with performance, but there are a number of "low-hanging fruits" in here, including [variable types not declared](https://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/VariableTypeNotDeclared) and [implicit ActiveSheet references](https://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitActiveSheetReference) (these are a very common cause of bugs), that Rubberduck can quickly find and fix for you in this code. Also note that `Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2"))` is exactly equivalent to `Range("E2")`; worksheet reads/writes need to be limited to achieve better performance.

Comment: Rubberduck inspections would also flag many of these variables for not using a meaningful identifier name, and the `ta` loop is iterating every single row across 4 columns, one by one: I suspect that's where more of the time is being spent.

Comment: I thought you said "small"?

Answer (score 12):

You do not have look at more than about 2 *Code Review* answers to find posts that advocate two very important principles when writing code (in VBA or any other language).  The "Do not repeat yourself" principle ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) and the "Single Responsibility Principle" ([SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)).  These two principles are important for writing efficient, readable, and correct code.  So, getting to faster execution is *easier* if your code is implemented using the DRY and SRP principles.

Regarding execution speed, `Union` can be a [slow operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29230757/how-to-make-union-range-faster-for-large-loops).  So, the suggestions below include refactoring the code in order to remove the use of `Union` by applying DRY and SRP.

SRP:

SRP advocates that each procedure fulfills a single responsibility for the program.  When SRP is applied, long procedures naturally are broken down into smaller procedures.  The result is code that is generally more reliable, readable, and efficient.

The posted Subroutine `a_organizar_protocolo` is composed of 249 lines.  This is too many lines for most procedures (especially if they are fulfilling a single responsibility).  Subroutine `a_organizar_protocolo` has the following responsibilities:

- Handle toggling Application flags
- Formats Cells
- Updates Content

The entry point procedure can fulfill the Application flag handling responsibility:

```
Sub a_organizar_protocolo()

    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Interactive = False
    
On Error GoTo ErrorExit

    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 90
    
    FormatContent
    
    UpdateValues

    Cells.Validation.Delete
    Cells.FormatConditions.Delete

    Range("E2").End(xlDown).Select

ResetFlags:    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Interactive = True

    Exit Sub
ErrorExit:
    Debug.Print "Error: " & Err.Description
    Goto ResetFlags
End Sub
```

**ErrorHandling:**

In the posted code, using `On Error Resume Next` at the top of the subroutine ignores every error that occurs during execution.  There are times when ignoring all errors is appropriate...this is probably not one of them.  It's possible that *many* errors are occurring within this subroutine - I cannot say for sure.  More importantly, neither can you.

My suspicion is that `On Error Resume Next' was added to guarantee that the Application flags reset lines are executed.  In the example above, it is now clear that the response to an error is to print an error message to the *Immediate Window* and reset the Application flags.  And, a single error cancels the operation.

DRY: Code expressions that are repeated but with different constant strings/numbers result in code that is:

- More difficult to read
- Prone to typos
- More difficult to maintain

Where possible use code to reduce how much content is required to accomplish and update the necessary tasks. In the posted code, the same 'type' of operations are performed on columns "A" through "R".  Using arrays and the `Split` function, these can be refactored to reduce repeated expressions.

The code:

```
    Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 15
    Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 14
    Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 20
    Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 30
    Columns("E:E").ColumnWidth = 14
    Columns("F:F").ColumnWidth = 11
    Columns("G:G").ColumnWidth = 40
    Columns("H:H").ColumnWidth = 14
    Columns("I:I").ColumnWidth = 14
    Columns("J:J").ColumnWidth = 16
    Columns("K:K").ColumnWidth = 20
    Columns("L:L").ColumnWidth = 10
    Columns("M:M").ColumnWidth = 8
    Columns("N:N").ColumnWidth = 12
    Columns("O:O").ColumnWidth = 5
    Columns("P:P").ColumnWidth = 14
    Columns("Q:R").ColumnWidth = 25 'Columns("Q:R") could be a typo error(?)

    Range("A1").Value = "Lançamento"
    Range("B1").Value = "Data de Recebimento"
    Range("C1").Value = "Solicitante"
    Range("D1").Value = "Espécie do Documento"
    Range("E1").Value = "Número da Nota Fiscal"
    Range("F1").Value = "Código do Fornecedor"
    Range("G1").Value = "Fornecedor"
    Range("H1").Value = "Centro de Custo"
    Range("I1").Value = "Vencimento"
    Range("J1").Value = "Valor"
    Range("K1").Value = "Descrição"
    Range("L1").Value = "Pedido"
    Range("M1").Value = "Item do Pedido"
    Range("N1").Value = "Pagamento"
    Range("O1").Value = "Validação"
    Range("P1").Value = "Prioridade"
    Range("Q1").Value = "Observação"
    Range("R1").Value = "Concatenar"
```

Can be refactored to:

```
    Dim columnFormatDefinitions As String
    columnFormatDefinitions = _
        "A:Lançamento:15," & _
        "B:Data de Recebimento:14," & _
        "C:Solicitante:20," & _
        "D:Espécie do Documento:30," & _
        "E:Número da Nota Fiscal:14," & _
        "F:Código do Fornecedor:11," & _
        "G:Fornecedor:40," & _
        "H:Centro de Custo:14," & _
        "I:Vencimento:14," & _
        "J:Valor:16," & _
        "K:Descrição:20," & _
        "L:Pedido:10," & _
        "M:Item do Pedido:8," & _
        "N:Pagamento:12," & _
        "O:Validação:5," & _
        "P:Prioridade:14," & _
        "Q:Observação:25," & _
        "R:Concatenar:25"
        
    Dim colLetter As String
    Dim colWidth As Long
    Dim colHeader As String
    Dim formatDefinition As Variant
    
    Dim formatElements As Variant
    For Each formatDefinition In Split(columnFormatDefinitions, ",")
        
        formatElements = Split(formatDefinition, ":")
        colLetter = formatElements(0)
        colHeader = formatElements(1)
        colWidth = CLng(formatElements(2))
        
        Columns(colLetter & ":" & colLetter).ColumnWidth = colWidth
        Range(colLetter & "1").Value = colHeader
    Next
```

Usually refactoring using the DRY priniciple results in fewer lines of code.  That is not really the case here.  What the refactored code *does* accomplish is the removal of all the repeated lines containing the expression `Columns("X:X").ColumnWidth = ##`.  And, in the future, when column "S" is added, only "S:XXXX:##" needs to be added to the `columnFormatDefinitions` string.  Also, if `Columns("Q:R")` is a typo, this kind of error is more easily found.

**Union:**

The code:

```
    Dim qa, q1, q2, q3 As Range
    Set q1 = Range(Range("G2"), Range("G" & Rows.Count))
    Set q2 = Range(Range("J2"), Range("K" & Rows.Count))
    Set q3 = Range(Range("Q2"), Range("R" & Rows.Count))
    Set qa = Union(q1, q2, q3)
    qa.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
```

relies on creating a `Union` of `Ranges` in order to apply horizontal alignment.  However by using a helper subroutine the use of a `Union` can be avoided.

Using SRP and DRY, refactor this code into a helper subroutine:

Replace the code block above with:

```
ApplyHorizontalAlignment "G", "J", "Q"
```

Where ApplyHorizontalAlignment is:

```
Private Sub ApplyHorizontalAlignment(ParamArray colLtrs() As Variant)
    
    Dim rangeOfInterest As Range
    Dim cLtr As Variant
    For Each cLtr In colLtrs
        Set rangeOfInterest = Range(Range(cLtr & "2"), Range(cLtr & Rows.Count))
        rangeOfInterest.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    Next
End Sub
```

This same approach can be used to eliminate all uses of `Union` which may result is some efficiency improvements.

Putting it all together (with a couple more examples of removing the use of `Union`):

```
'Best Practice: Always declare Option Explicit at the top of your modules.
'Doing so requires all variable/fields to be declared before they are used
'or the code does not compile

Option Explicit

Sub a_organizar_protocolo()

    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Interactive = False
    
On Error GoTo ErrorExit

    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 90

    Columns("O:P").ClearContents
    Columns("R:R").ClearContents

    FormatContent
    
    UpdateValues
    
    Cells.Validation.Delete
    Cells.FormatConditions.Delete

    Range("E2").End(xlDown).Select

ResetFlags:    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Interactive = True

    Exit Sub
ErrorExit:
    Debug.Print "Error: " & Err.Description
    Goto ResetFlags
End Sub

Private Sub FormatContent()

    With Cells
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
        With .Borders
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With .Font
            .Name = "Calibri"
            .Size = 11
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Bold = False
            .Italic = False
        End With
    End With

    With Rows("1:1")
        .RowHeight = 32
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 49
        .WrapText = True
        With .Font
            .Size = 12
            .Bold = True
            .ColorIndex = 44
        End With
    End With

    With ActiveWindow
        .FreezePanes = False
        .SplitColumn = 0
        .SplitRow = 1
        .FreezePanes = True
    End With

    With Rows("2:" & Rows.Count)
        .RowHeight = 15
        .Interior.Color = xlNone
    End With
    
    FormatHeaders
    
    ApplyHorizontalAlignment "G", "J", "Q"

End Sub

Private Sub FormatHeaders()
    'Create a set of delimited format strings of the form <columnLetter:columnName:columnWidth>
    Dim columnFormatDefinitions As String
    columnFormatDefinitions = _
        "A:Lançamento:15," & _
        "B:Data de Recebimento:14," & _
        "C:Solicitante:20," & _
        "D:Espécie do Documento:30," & _
        "E:Número da Nota Fiscal:14," & _
        "F:Código do Fornecedor:11," & _
        "G:Fornecedor:40," & _
        "H:Centro de Custo:14," & _
        "I:Vencimento:14," & _
        "J:Valor:16," & _
        "K:Descrição:20," & _
        "L:Pedido:10," & _
        "M:Item do Pedido:8," & _
        "N:Pagamento:12," & _
        "O:Validação:5," & _
        "P:Prioridade:14," & _
        "Q:Observação:25," & _
        "R:Concatenar:25"
        
    Dim colLetter As String
    Dim colWidth As Long
    Dim colHeader As String
    Dim formatDefinition As Variant
    
    Dim formatElements As Variant
    For Each formatDefinition In Split(columnFormatDefinitions, ",")
        
        formatElements = Split(formatDefinition, ":")
        colLetter = formatElements(0)
        colHeader = formatElements(1)
        colWidth = CLng(formatElements(2))
        
        Columns(colLetter & ":" & colLetter).ColumnWidth = colWidth
        Range(colLetter & "1").Value = colHeader
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ApplyHorizontalAlignment(ParamArray colLtrs() As Variant)
    
    Dim rangeOfInterest As Range
    Dim cLtr As Variant
    For Each cLtr In colLtrs
        Set rangeOfInterest = Range(Range(cLtr & "2"), Range(cLtr & Rows.Count))
        rangeOfInterest.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    Next
End Sub


Private Sub UpdateValues()
    ReplaceSomeCharacters "G", "K"
    'ReplaceSomeCharacters replaces the code below
'    Dim ea, e1, e2 As Range
'    Set e1 = Range(Range("G2"), Range("G2").End(xlDown))
'    Set e2 = Range(Range("K2"), Range("K2").End(xlDown))
'    Set ea = Union(e1, e2)
'    With ea
'        .Replace What:=".", Replacement:=""
'        .Replace What:="/", Replacement:=""
'        .Replace What:=":", Replacement:=""
'        .Replace What:="–", Replacement:="-"
'    End With
    

    Dim r0, ra As Range
    Set r0 = Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlDown))
    For Each ra In r0
        If Len(ra.Value) > 9 Then ra.Value = Right(ra.Value, 9)
    Next
    r0.Replace What:="x", Replacement:="0"

    Dim ta, tb As Range
    Dim t1, t2, t3, t4 As Range
    
    Dim t0 As Long
    
    t0 = Range("E:E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    
    ClearNonNumerics t0, "E2:E", "F2:F", "H2:H", "L2:M"
    'ClearNonNumerics replaces the code below
'    Set t1 = Range("E2:E" & t0)
'    Set t2 = Range("F2:F" & t0)
'    Set t3 = Range("H2:H" & t0)
'    Set t4 = Range("L2:M" & t0)
'    Set tb = Union(t1, t2, t3, t4)
'
'    Dim tc As String
'    Dim td As String
'    Dim te As String
'    Dim t As Long
'
'    For Each ta In tb
'        tc = ""
'        For t = 1 To Len(ta.Value)
'            td = Mid(ta.Value, t, 1)
'            If td Like "[0-9]" Then
'                te = td
'            Else
'                te = ""
'            End If
'        tc = tc & te
'        Next t
'        ta.Value = tc
'    Next

    Dim ya, yb As Range
    Set yb = Range(Range("J2"), Range("J2").End(xlDown))
    
    Dim yc As String
    Dim yd As String
    Dim ye As String
    Dim y As Long
    
    For Each ya In yb
        yc = ""
        For y = 1 To Len(ya.Value)
            yd = Mid(ya.Value, y, 1)
            If yd Like "[0-9],-" Then
                ye = yd
            Else
                ye = ""
            End If
        yc = yc & ye
        Next y
        ya.Value = yc * 1
    Next

    Dim ia, ib As Range
    Set ib = Range(Range("J2"), Range("J2").End(xlDown))

    For Each ia In ib
        If ia.Value < 0 Then
            With ia
                .Offset(0, -1).Value = "31/12/" & (Year(Date) + 1)
                .Offset(0, -2).Value = "NA"
                .Offset(0, 2).Value = "NA"
                .Offset(0, 3).Value = "NA"
            End With
        End If
    Next

    Dim oa, ob As Range
    Set ob = Range(Range("D2"), Range("D2").End(xlDown))

    For Each oa In ob
        If oa.Value = "Ouvidoria" Then
            With oa
                .Offset(0, -1).Value = oa.Value
                .Offset(0, 8).Value = "NA"
                .Offset(0, 9).Value = "NA"
                .Offset(0, 10).Value = "DEPÓSITO"
            End With
        End If
    Next

    Dim pa, pb, p1, p2 As Range

    Set p1 = Columns("H:H").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    For Each pa In p1
        pa.Value = "Estoque"
    Next

    Set p2 = Range(Range("H2"), Range("H2").End(xlDown))
    For Each pb In p2
        If pb.Value = "Estoque" Then pb.Offset(0, -7).Value = pb.Value
    Next

    Dim k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, ka, kb, kaa, kbb As Range
    Set k1 = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    Set k2 = Range(Range("C2"), Range("C2").End(xlDown))
    Set k3 = Range(Range("G2"), Range("G2").End(xlDown))
    Set k4 = Range(Range("K2"), Range("K2").End(xlDown))
    Set k5 = Range(Range("N2"), Range("N2").End(xlDown))
    Set ka = Union(k1, k2)
    Set kb = Union(k3, k4, k5)
    
    For Each kaa In ka
        kaa.Value = StrConv(kaa.Value, vbProperCase)
    Next kaa

    For Each kbb In kb
        kbb.Value = UCase(kbb.Value)
    Next kbb

End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceSomeCharacters (ParamArray colLtrs() As Variant)
    
    Dim rangeOfInterest As Range
    Dim cLtr As Variant
    For Each cLtr In colLtrs
        Set rangeOfInterest = Range(Range(cLtr & "2"), Range(cLtr & "2").End(xlDown))
        With rangeOfInterest
            .Replace What:=".", Replacement:=""
            .Replace What:="/", Replacement:=""
            .Replace What:=":", Replacement:=""
            .Replace What:="–", Replacement:="-"
        End With
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ClearNonNumerics(ByVal eRow As Long, ParamArray rangeExpressions() As Variant)
    Dim tc As String
    Dim td As String
    Dim te As String
    Dim t As Long

    Dim rangeOfInterest As Range
    Dim rangeExpression As Variant
    For Each rangeExpression In rangeExpressions
        Set rangeOfInterest = Range(rangeExpression & eRow)
        tc = ""
        For t = 1 To Len(rangeOfInterest.Value)
            td = Mid(rangeOfInterest.Value, t, 1)
            If td Like "[0-9]" Then
                te = td
            Else
                te = ""
            End If
            tc = tc & te
        Next t
        
        rangeOfInterest .Value = tc
    Next

End Sub
```

To find where your code's performance is poor with some precision, you can add a small subroutine like:

```
Sub MarkTime(ByVal locationIdentifier As String)
    Debug.Print Now() & " :" & locationIdentifier
End Sub
```

Calling this subroutine from the entrance and exit of all subroutines will print timestamps with 1 second resolution.  The output can be evaluated to find the slowest blocks of code.

Comment: This is beautiful.

Answer (score 7):

Diagnosing bad code performance is actually not too hard once you know the standard approach. It comes down to two (maybe three) things:

1. Identify which sections of the code are slow
2. Work out why they are slow (often from a standard set of reasons)
3. (Fix it - often from a standard set of fixes)

#### 1. Identify which sections of the code are slow

There are two ways to do this. The first, if you have no idea whatsoever, you *profile* your code. Profiling can be very simple:

```
Sub slowCode()
    Dim startTime As Single
    startTime = Timer

    process_one 'do something
    Debug.Print "Reached location one at t="; Timer - startTime

    process_two 'do something else
    Debug.Print "Reach location two at t="; Timer - startTime

    For i = 1 to 5
         process_three 'do something in a loop
    Next i
    Debug.Print "Reached End at t="; Timer - startTime
End Sub
```

That might output

```
Reached location one at t=0.1223
Reached location two at t=7.342    '<---This looks like the slow step location 1->2
Reached End at t=7.554
```

For complex situations you can reach for a profiling library [like the one I wrote](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/194859/146810). But often *debug.print* a few timestamps allows you to find the really slow bit.

The second method, which you can see in the comments, is to use a "rule of thumb" or educated guess, which for VBA - a language used to process spreadsheet data - the rule of thumb is to look for nested `For`/`For Each` loops (i.e., a loop within a loop) that iterate over cells in the worksheet, and *assume* that is the slow part of the code. If that sounds hand-wavy it's because it is; method 1 is always going to be more precise. But surprisingly, *it's not that bad*. Let me explain a little why it works:

VBA is a slow uncompiled language compared to C++ or something, but really it's not that slow, used correctly it can write blazingly fast applications. For that reason, typically we find that the code we write is pretty instantaneous for a small range of cells, it's only when we increase to a larger set of data that things become unbearably slow. That's where `For` loops come in. Consider this made-up code:

```vb
Sub DoAThing(ByVal data As Range)

    'process_1
    Debug.Print "Number of cells = "; data.Rows.Count * data.Columns.Count

    'process 2
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In data
        cell.Value = 420
    Next cell

End Sub
```

It is important to notice two things:

1. The whole Sub `DoAThing` can be split into two distinct sections:

   - The first section that calculates the number of cells by multiplication
   - The second section which is a loop over the cells in the dataset
2. For the first process *it does not matter how big* `data` is and how many cells are in it. The operation will take the same amount of time regardless, because obtaining the dimensions of a big rectangle is just as easy/difficult as obtaining the dimensions of a little rectangle. In contrast, for process 2 it *does* matter how big `data` is. In fact, the more cells are in the dataset, the longer it will take to change the value in every one of them*.

*It'll actually be proportional, double the number of cells and you expect it to take twice as long.

---

Now, imagine running this Sub over just a few cells. It would run in the blink of an eye, both process 1 and 2 would take basically 0 seconds. But what happens if we do this over a really big dataset? Which process would be the culprit for the Sub taking a long time?

The second one of course, since it gets slower and slower as the data grows, so if we want to speed things up we can basically *ignore* process 1 and focus purely on process 2. This logic extends further. If we have this code:

```
Sub DoSomeNestedLoops(ByVal data As Range)

    'process 1
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In data
        doASlowThing
    Next cell

    'process 2
    Dim cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range
    For Each cell1 In data
        For Each cell2 In data
            doAFastThing
        Next cell2
    Next cell1
End Sub
```

Now process 2 has a *nested `For` loop*. This means if there are 10 cells in the dataset, we will call `doAFastThing` 10*10=100 times!

So of course for a really big dataset process 2 is going to be the slow part. There's a subtle point here though: for 10 cells of data, in process 1 we call `doASlowThing` 10 times, and in process 2 we call `doAFastThing` 100 times. Actually process 1 might still take longer in total for a small number of cells, if `10*slow > 100*fast`. However, we can be sure, if we have 1000 or 1 million cells, process 2 will start to dominate.

Hmm, this rule of thumb is getting complicated, and in fact there's a lot more to talk about here (algorithmic complexity, big O notation, vectorisation, etc.) so I'll leave it there and say that **if in doubt** method 1 (profiling) will always work, and method 2 of spotting the nested loops is a good approximation for when big data is at play, but only experience will give you the same level of intuition as some of the commenters on this (just look how many internet points they have!).

#### 2. Work out why they are slow (often from a standard set of reasons)

So we found the slow bit of code that needs to be optimised (the rest we can ignore). Here's why code might be slow specifically in Excel VBA:

- Reading data from the sheet to VBA one cell at a time rather than all in one go.
- Writing data from VBA to the sheet 1 cell at a time, forcing the screen to repaint, forcing worksheet functions to calculate over and over again .
- Performing complicated mathematical operations in VBA (uncompiled, single thread) rather than using worksheet functions (compiled, multi-thread) or a VBA library
- `Select`ing or `Activate`ing sheets and ranges rather than referring to them directly by name (you don't make this mistake)
- That's basically it to be honest, as far as typical Excel VBA use cases go.

There are more advanced ones related to memory allocation, using the appropriate data structures, and other quirks like autosave. That's what *Code Review* is for, so well done for posting:)

#### (3. Standard fixes)

Those standard problems all have pretty standard fixes

- Rather than looping over cells when reading or writing, read/write an array of data only once and do the looping in VBA
- If you must perform multiple writes to the worksheet, then turn off automatic calculations, screen updates, freezpanes etc. If you write only once then this will not be an issue.
- Use named ranges and worksheet functions more! VBA is designed to integrate really closely with Excel, so my VBA apps generally do most of the calculating in the worksheet, and just a bit of automation from VBA. Why not make a template worksheet with all formatting and headers, copy the data in then copy+paste values to freeze the result?

#### Code

This is a short demo of the diagnosing performance issues approach for your code. To do this, first split your code into blocks to identify the most deeply nested portion with respect to the amount of data you run it on:

> ```
> Sub a_organizar_protocolo()
>     On Error Resume Next
>
>     Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
>     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
>     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
>     Application.EnableEvents = False
>     Application.InterActive = False
>
>     ActiveWorkbook.Save
>
>     ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
>
>     ActiveWindow.Zoom = 90
>
>     Columns("O:P").ClearContents
>     Columns("R:R").ClearContents
>
>     With Cells
>         .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
>         .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
>         .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
>         .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
>         .WrapText = False
>         .Orientation = 0
>         .AddIndent = False
>         .IndentLevel = 0
>         .ShrinkToFit = False
>         .ReadingOrder = xlContext
>         .MergeCells = False
>         With .Borders
>             .LineStyle = xlContinuous
>             .ColorIndex = 0
>             .Weight = xlThin
>         End With
>         With .Font
>             .Name = "Calibri"
>             .Size = 11
>             .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
>             .Bold = False
>             .Italic = False
>         End With
>     End With
>
>     With Rows("1:1")
>         .RowHeight = 32
>         .Interior.ColorIndex = 49
>         .WrapText = True
>         With .Font
>             .Size = 12
>             .Bold = True
>             .ColorIndex = 44
>         End With
>     End With
>
>     With ActiveWindow
>         .FreezePanes = False
>         .SplitColumn = 0
>         .SplitRow = 1
>         .FreezePanes = True
>     End With
>
>     With Rows("2:" & Rows.Count)
>         .RowHeight = 15
>         .Interior.Color = xlNone
>     End With
>
>     Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 15
>     Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 14
>     Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 20
>     Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 30
>     Columns("E:E").ColumnWidth = 14
>     Columns("F:F").ColumnWidth = 11
>     Columns("G:G").ColumnWidth = 40
>     Columns("H:H").ColumnWidth = 14
>     Columns("I:I").ColumnWidth = 14
>     Columns("J:J").ColumnWidth = 16
>     Columns("K:K").ColumnWidth = 20
>     Columns("L:L").ColumnWidth = 10
>     Columns("M:M").ColumnWidth = 8
>     Columns("N:N").ColumnWidth = 12
>     Columns("O:O").ColumnWidth = 5
>     Columns("P:P").ColumnWidth = 14
>     Columns("Q:R").ColumnWidth = 25
>
>     Range("A1").Value = "Lançamento"
>     Range("B1").Value = "Data de Recebimento"
>     Range("C1").Value = "Solicitante"
>     Range("D1").Value = "Espécie do Documento"
>     Range("E1").Value = "Número da Nota Fiscal"
>     Range("F1").Value = "Código do Fornecedor"
>     Range("G1").Value = "Fornecedor"
>     Range("H1").Value = "Centro de Custo"
>     Range("I1").Value = "Vencimento"
>     Range("J1").Value = "Valor"
>     Range("K1").Value = "Descrição"
>     Range("L1").Value = "Pedido"
>     Range("M1").Value = "Item do Pedido"
>     Range("N1").Value = "Pagamento"
>     Range("O1").Value = "Validação"
>     Range("P1").Value = "Prioridade"
>     Range("Q1").Value = "Observação"
>     Range("R1").Value = "Concatenar"
> ```

All that is fine and works in constant time (independent of the number of cells of data). It's not making your code slow I don't think.

---

> ```
>     Dim qa, q1, q2, q3 As Range
>     Set q1 = Range(Range("G2"), Range("G" & Rows.Count))
>     Set q2 = Range(Range("J2"), Range("K" & Rows.Count))
>     Set q3 = Range(Range("Q2"), Range("R" & Rows.Count))
>     Set qa = Union(q1, q2, q3)
>     qa.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
>
>     Dim ea, e1, e2 As Range
>     Set e1 = Range(Range("G2"), Range("G2").End(xlDown))
>     Set e2 = Range(Range("K2"), Range("K2").End(xlDown))
>     Set ea = Union(e1, e2)
>     With ea
>         .Replace What:=".", Replacement:=""
>         .Replace What:="/", Replacement:=""
>         .Replace What:=":", Replacement:=""
>         .Replace What:="–", Replacement:="-"
>     End With
> ```

This code's performance scales linearly with the number of rows in your dataset. However, you don't loop, but use the `.Replace` function which is clever. It'll still get twice as slow if you have twice as many rows, but you delegate the looping to Excel (compiled) rather than looping in VBA (uncompiled), so you make each iteration of the loop faster.

---

> ```
>     Dim r0, ra As Range
>     Set r0 = Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlDown))
>     For Each ra In r0
>         If Len(ra.Value) > 9 Then ra.Value = Right(ra.Value, 9)
>     Next
>     r0.Replace What:="x", Replacement:="0"
> ```

Scales linearly with number of rows, as above.

---

> ```
>     Dim ta, tb As Range
>     Dim t1, t2, t3, t4 As Range
>     t0 = Range("E:E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
>     Set t1 = Range("E2:E" & t0)
>     Set t2 = Range("F2:F" & t0)
>     Set t3 = Range("H2:H" & t0)
>     Set t4 = Range("L2:M" & t0)
>     Set tb = Union(t1, t2, t3, t4)
>
>     For Each ta In tb
>         tc = ""
>         For t = 1 To Len(ta.Value)
>             td = Mid(ta.Value, t, 1)
>             If td Like "[0-9]" Then
>                 te = td
>             Else
>                 te = ""
>             End If
>         tc = tc & te
>         Next t
>         ta.Value = tc
>     Next
>     Dim ya, yb As Range
>     Set yb = Range(Range("J2"), Range("J2").End(xlDown))
>
>     For Each ya In yb
>         yc = ""
>         For y = 1 To Len(ya.Value)
>             yd = Mid(ya.Value, y, 1)
>             If yd Like "[0-9],-" Then
>                 ye = yd
>             Else
>                 ye = ""
>             End If
>         yc = yc & ye
>         Next y
>         ya.Value = yc * 1
>     Next
> ```

Both these loops scale linearly with the number of rows, but then also linearly with the average length of text in each cell. You also work on 5 columns, this is slow. For N rows of data you write to the sheet 5N times.

---

> ```
>     Dim ia, ib As Range
>     Set ib = Range(Range("J2"), Range("J2").End(xlDown))
>
>     For Each ia In ib
>         If ia.Value < 0 Then
>             With ia
>                 .Offset(0, -1).Value = "31/12/" & (Year(Date) + 1)
>                 .Offset(0, -2).Value = "NA"
>                 .Offset(0, 2).Value = "NA"
>                 .Offset(0, 3).Value = "NA"
>             End With
>         End If
>     Next
>
>     Dim oa, ob As Range
>     Set ob = Range(Range("D2"), Range("D2").End(xlDown))
>
>     For Each oa In ob
>         If oa.Value = "Ouvidoria" Then
>             With oa
>                 .Offset(0, -1).Value = oa.Value
>                 .Offset(0, 8).Value = "NA"
>                 .Offset(0, 9).Value = "NA"
>                 .Offset(0, 10).Value = "DEPÓSITO"
>             End With
>         End If
>     Next
> ```

With those offsets you write to the sheet 8N times for N rows of data.

> ```
>     Dim pa, pb, p1, p2 As Range
>
>     Set p1 = Columns("H:H").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
>     For Each pa In p1
>         pa.Value = "Estoque"
>     Next
>
>     Set p2 = Range(Range("H2"), Range("H2").End(xlDown))
>     For Each pb In p2
>         If pb.Value = "Estoque" Then pb.Offset(0, -7).Value = pb.Value
>     Next
>
>     Dim k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, ka, kb, kaa, kbb As Range
>     Set k1 = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))
>     Set k2 = Range(Range("C2"), Range("C2").End(xlDown))
>     Set k3 = Range(Range("G2"), Range("G2").End(xlDown))
>     Set k4 = Range(Range("K2"), Range("K2").End(xlDown))
>     Set k5 = Range(Range("N2"), Range("N2").End(xlDown))
>     Set ka = Union(k1, k2)
>     Set kb = Union(k3, k4, k5)
>
>     For Each kaa In ka
>         kaa.Value = StrConv(kaa.Value, vbProperCase)
>     Next kaa
>
>     For Each kbb In kb
>         kbb.Value = UCase(kbb.Value)
>     Next kbb
> ```

These loops are all linear with number of rows of data.

---

Because all loops are linear with data size, no single operation will dominate as the data gets larger (well, that first block of code is constant time, so it shouldn't dominate performance as the data grows). Therefore you need to profile these loops to find which is actually slow.

---

BTW: This `Dim k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, ka, kb, kaa, kbb As Range` doesn't do what you think it does. `kbb` gets declared as `Range`, but all the others are implicitly `Variant`. You need `Dim k1 As Range, k2 As Range, ... kbb As Range`, at which point you may as well split over multiple lines.

Comment: VBA is compiled to Microsoft P-code, it is not an uncompiled language - not that it affects your answer a lot.

Comment: @eirikdaude You are partially correct. Compiling to P-code it just an intermediary step because P-code gets interpreted by a virtual machine. So, VBA is not compiled overall which makes it slower than compiled languages like C.

Comment: @CristianBuse Would you likewise argue that e.g. Java isn't a compiled language, because the bytecode it's compiled to is interpreted by a virtual machine?

Comment: @eirikdaude: it is not that simple. VBA's bytecode interpreter isn't famous for being very fast, especially in comparison to the common Java bytecode JIT compilers. However, VBA program's are usually running directly in-process with Excel, which sometimes give a noteable performance benefit in comparision to an equivalent out-of-process approach, which most Java programs would require for controlling Excel.

Comment: Yes, but my point of contention isn't whether it is fast or not, but whether it is correct to say the code isn't compiled. Tbh. I am not familiar enough with the implementation of either the java vm or microsoft's to say how significant their differences are. I do note that both java and vba are noted as examples of languages compiled to p-code on the wikipedia page for that though. It's a minor point anyway, which doesn't alter the answer in any significant way. @DocBrown

Comment: @eirikdaude Interesting discussion, I would add that IIUC, VBA p-code opcodes are a 1:1 mapping with raw VBA code (VBA in the editor goes through a round trip conversion to p-code and back as you type). I don't know if this is true for java opcodes but I believe not as there is some optimisation. VBA p-code is basically just pre-parsed and tokenised VBA and is still interpreted, as opposed to compilation which most people think of as outputting executable machine code. So I don't think it's misleading to say VBA is not compiled. And yes it has no bearing on the gist of the answer IMO.

Comment: @eirikdaude Modern JVMs use just-in-time compilation to compile bytecode to native CPU instructions at runtime. Python compiles to bytecode which is then executed by a VM as the program runs. Python is generally considered to be interpreted so why not Java? I guess Java is mostly considered compiled because bytecode can also be compiled ahead of time as opposed to just-in-time. But, when it comes to just-in-time compilation it can be argued that Java is both compiled and interpreted.

Comment: @eirikdaude We can apply the same logic for VBA. The code displayed in the VBE gets compiled/tokenised to Op-code each time the Enter key is pressed. When running code or Debug.Compile is executed, the Op-code gets compiled to P-code/Ex-code. Then P-code is compiled to native binary code at runtime by the virtual machine. Like Java, we can argue that VBA is both compiled and interpreted. Depending on how we frame the argument, we can argue both sides. I don't think it's misleading to say VBA is not compiled but I understand the reason for your comment.